# Difference between Session and HttpContext.Current.Session

Tags: asp.net

What is the difference between Session and HttpContext.Current.Session object?

Comment: It is worth clarifying that when you say 'session', you are referring to System.Web.UI.Page.Session. The Session object is available inside the context of the ASP.NET page.

Answer (score 117):

A little late here, but here's something I just discovered.

@Phillipe Leybaert and @CSharpAtl are both incorrect. `HttpApplication`'s `Session` property exhibits different behaviour than does that of the property `HttpContext.Current.Session`. They will both return a reference to the same `HttpSessionState` instance **if** one is available. They differ in what they do when there is no instance of `HttpSessionState` available for the current request.

Not all `HttpHandler`s provide session state. To do so, the `HttpHandler` **must** implement [one or both?] the marker interfaces `IRequiresSessionState` or `IReadOnlySessionState`.

`HttpContext.Current.Session` simply returns `null` if there is no session available.

The `HttpApplication`'s implementation of the `Session` property throws an `HttpException` with the message `Session state is not available in this context.` rather than returning a `null` reference.

Some examples of `HttpHandler` that do not implement session are the default handlers for normally static resources, such as image and CSS files. Any reference to the `HttpApplication`'s `Session` property in such cases (as in `global.asax` event handlers) will result an `HttpException` being thrown.

Needless to say, the unexpected `HttpException` provides a WTF?! moment if you're not expecting it.

The `Session` property of the `HttpApplication` class is implemented thus (from Reflector):

```
[Browsable(false), DesignerSerializationVisibility(DesignerSerializationVisibility.Hidden)]
public HttpSessionState Session
{
  get
  {
    HttpSessionState session = null;

    if (this._session != null)
    {
        session = this._session;
    }
    else if (this._context != null)
    {
        session = this._context.Session;
    }

    if (session == null)
    {
        throw new HttpException(SR.GetString("Session_not_available"));
    }

    return session;
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for putting the effort in to fill out a better answer.

Comment: No problem. I had just had a rather annoying WTF? moment that took some time to sort out. I figured I'd document it so somebody else down the line wouldn't have to spend the time figuring out what was going on.

Answer (score 8):

There is no difference.

The getter for Page.Session returns the context session.

Answer (score 2):

Nothing. `Session` just points to the `HttpContext.Current.Session`.

Answer (score 1):

**Internally, Page.Session points to *It's* HttpContext.Current.Session only, but there are still two differences depending on from where it's called.**

Page.Session can be accessed only from classes inherited from System.Web.UI.Page and it will throw HttpException when accessed from WebMethod.
 Where as HttpContext.Current.Session can be accessed from anywhere as long as you're running in the context of a web application. 
Other important difference where you can access Page.Session but cannot access HttpContext.Current.Session : 
 If there is a method named GetData in your page(inherited from System.Web.UI.Page) which is executed concurrently in different threads from some other page method, GetData method can access the Page.Seession, but you cannot access HttpContext.Current.Session. 
 It's because GetData has been called from different thread so HttpContext.Current is null and HttpContext.Current.Session will throw null reference exception, but Page.Session will still be attached with page object so page method GetData can access the Page.Session.