# Difference between HttpContext.Current.Response and Context.Response?

Tags: c#, asp.net, http, web

I want to know the difference between `HttpContext.Current.Response` and `Context.Response` and when I should be used and which is better.

Comment: possible duplicate of [HttpContext.Current.Session vs Context.Session](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14207775/httpcontext-current-session-vs-context-session)

Comment: Which `Context.Response` do you actually mean?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those are just different ways to access the same object.

The `Context` property is available inside some objects. If your code is not within one of those objects, you can use the static `HttpContext.Current` property to access the current context.

Answer (score 2):

There is no difference. Some classes, e.g. Page provide a property Context that returns HttpContext.Current and can be used as a short form.

Answer (score 1):

No difference at all.  It's the same object, but accessed differently.