# Why can't Session variable be accessed outside a method?

Tags: asp.net, web

I am a new user of ASP.NET and was trying to segregate every page into variables, events and methods. I use a session variable that is used inside almost every method and event. So instead of extracting it from every method and storing it inside a variable, I tried to extract it on a page level. But the keyword 'Session' is not recognised outside a variable. Why is that?

```
public partial class OnCall_OnCall_History : System.Web.UI.Page
{
#region Variables
string ID = Convert.ToString(Session["ID"]);  //Not allowed 
#endregion

#region PageLoad
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
       string ID  = (string)(Session["ID"]); //Allowed
    }
}
#endregion
```

}

Answer (score 1):

That's because you are initialising variables in the declaration, then that assignment will be executed in the constructor. That happens before the properties of the `Page` object has been set up so that the page is aware that there is a request and a session.

Move those assignments inside an `Init` event handler. That event happens before the other events, but after the `Page` object has been set up properly.

That would look like this:

```
protected string ID;

protected void Page_Init(object sender, EventArgs e) {
  ID = Convert.ToString(Session["ID"]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why but you can use like this

```
string ID = Convert.ToString(HttpContext.Current.Session["ID"]);
```

So your code can be

```
public partial class OnCall_OnCall_History : System.Web.UI.Page
{

    string ID = Convert.ToString(HttpContext.Current.Session["ID"]); 
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
              string ID  = (string)(Session["ID"]); //Allowed
         }
    }
}
```

Here is difference between both
[Difference between Session and HttpContext.Current.Session](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/940742/difference-between-session-and-httpcontext-current-session)
[What is the difference between these two HttpContext.Current.Session and Session - asp.net 4.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7954844/what-is-the-difference-between-these-two-httpcontext-current-session-and-session)

Comment: I just tried and it says: "Object reference not set to an instance of an object"

Answer (score 0):

Session object is available inside the context of the ASP.NET page. A request needs to be made for the asp.net page context, and therefore sessions, to be available.

Httpplication -> HttpContext - > HttpSession

I hope this helps.