# Accessing Session variable from class

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I start in a page that inherits from System.Web.UI.Page.  Page.Session is not null at this point.  The page creates a new class.  This class inherits from another class that inherits from System.Web.UI.UserControl.  Once I get into the class, Session is null.  What do I need for Session state to carry into the class?

Both the page and class are in the same webapp.

Comment: What means "once i get into the class"? The `Session` doesn't need to be _carried_, it's available in  the application after the user has visited the first page.(f.e via `HttpContext.Current.Session` as Hanlet has shown)

Comment: You say you create a new class that inherits from UserControl. Is the control on the page? How is it being instantiated?

Comment: If the control is on the page you should be able to do 'this.Page.Session' as well as 'HttpContext.Current.Session'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried using:

```
HttpContext.Current.Session
```

?

Good luck!

Comment: Works!  What is the difference with just Session where I got the null?

Comment: I think the difference is that HttpContext.Current.Session simply returns null if the session is not available, whereas your other class probably threw an exception. Check this out http://stackoverflow.com/a/6021261/752527