# How to store session data in .NET MVC 5

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

Can I use the `HttpContext.ApplicationInstance.Context` class to store session data using the `Session` function?
Or there is a better way to do this?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Normally the session is available as a property in your controller actions:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    this.Session["foo"] = "bar";
    return View();
}
```

Since the [`Session`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.controller.session(v=vs.118).aspx) property is of type `HttpSessionStateBase` it can be more easily mocked in a unit test. Please never use the static  `HttpContext.Current.Session` as you might see suggested elsewhere.

If you are not inside a controller action you can access the session if you have an instance of `HttpContextBase` (which is almost in every part of the MVC pipeline) using its Session property.

Comment: Why should one use the `Session` property instead of  `HttpContext.Current.Session`? 
I did a quick search on the difference, and I got [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6021261/5622941)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can apply data into a *Session* by utilizing the `HttpContext`.  You should be wary of such implementations though, *Model View Controller* is in nature *stateless*.  The session though will dictate some form of state.

You'll have to account for that, otherwise you could potentially introduce a large quantity of orphaned session variables if they're not accounted for.  Which could eat memory in your environment rapidly depending on your application.

If the application is small, you could easily do it with the following in your Controller:

```
HttpContext.Current.Session.Add("Title", "Data");
```