# Editing Partial Object in MVC without Actually Saving

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

My title is probably terrible because I'm having trouble wording what I am trying to do.

I have an object that can potentially contain a huge number of records that looks something like this:

```
public class AssignmentGenerator : BaseGenerator
{
    public bool IsLibrary { get; set; } = false;
    public List<LineItem> LineItems { get; set; } = new List<LineItem>();
}

public class LineItem
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Value { get; set; }
}
```

I have a form created that allows editing of the values of the object, but it is possible for the list of line items to become very large (one example I have is ~ 3000).  This being the case, I would like to make the line item list be a paged list in my view allowing editing of say 10 to 50 items at a time.
I've read a lot of tutorials and posts about how to do paging but none of the ones I've found go into how to do editing of a large set of data.  I don't want to save the changes on each page to the database until the user actually clicks on the Save button.  Is there a way to store the values in the object, retrieve them as needed, and then save upon user action?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The short answer is yes, there's a way - you're the programmer, you can do what you want. It's hard to give real code examples without more details, so below is just vague guidance.

You have to store their changes *somewhere*, but you can choose to save them in a staging database, or keep your AssignmentGenerator in memory on the server and just update the collection when they page (assuming 1 server or pinned sessions).

You will have to post the current state of the objects as the user changes pages (instead of just a Get endpoint). You don't have to save to the real database; you just update your temporary copy. The Save button should trigger a different controller action which moves your temporary copy to the real data store.

Comment: My experience is with win forms and services so I apologize if this is elementary.  To this my question would be, how do you maintain an object state in the controller?

Comment: You don't - definitely not in the controller itself I mean, that's shared. One option could be storing it as session data - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28154081 which can either be in-memory sessions or better yet backed by a distributed cache if the solutioni needs to be scalable. I'd recommend reading more on sessions first to understand how they work.