# I want tempdata to stay in the same place forever

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Controller

```
public async Task < IActionResult > Index(UserSignInViewModel p)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        var result = await _signInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(p.username, p.password, false, true);
        if (result.Succeeded)
        {
            TempData["kullanici"] = p.username;
            return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
        }
        else
        {
            return RedirectToAction("Index", "Login");
        }
    }
    return View();
}
```

Header

```
<div class="col-lg-9">
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg bg-light navbar-light py-3 py-lg-0 px-0">
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggler" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarCollapse">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse justify-content-between" id="navbarCollapse">
            <div class="navbar-nav mr-auto py-0">
                <a href="/" class="nav-item nav-link active">Ana Sayfa</a>
                <a asp-controller="Hakkımızda" asp-action="Index" class="nav-item nav-link">Hakkımızda</a>
                <a asp-controller="İletisim" asp-action="Index" class="nav-item nav-link">İletişim</a>
            </div>

            <span>@TempData["kullanici"]</span>
            <div class="navbar-nav ml-auto py-0">
                <a asp-controller="Login" asp-action="Index" class="nav-item nav-link">Giriş Yap</a>
                <a asp-controller="RegisterUser" asp-action="Index" class="nav-item nav-link">Kayıt Ol</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </nav>
</div>
```

In this controller, I take the user's username and display it in my header only once. However, I want this username to remain there until the session ends. I tried it with viewbag before, but I couldn't get the data.

I try ViewBag but it s not working.

Comment: TempData is for *temporary* storage of data: until it is read. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28154081/how-to-store-session-data-in-net-mvc-5

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thank you for your answers ! . But ı added some codes.

If you using "@HttpContext.Session" you should add this codes to your Startup.cs :

// ConfigureServices method in Startup.cs

```
services.AddSession();
```

// Configure method in Startup.cs

```
app.UseSession();

services.AddHttpContextAccessor();
```

And you should inject " IHttpContextAccessor" to your view code

```
@inject IHttpContextAccessor HttpContextAccessor
```

I use the code like this and it works:

```
<span>@HttpContextAccessor.HttpContext.Session.GetString("kullanici")</span>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use session variables bcoz, `TempData` is not suitable for your purpose because it is designed to store data for a single redirect and is meant to be short-lived.

First enable and configure sessions in your `Startup.cs`:

```
services.AddDistributedMemoryCache(); 
services.AddSession(options =>
{
    options.IdleTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(30); // Adjust the timeout as needed
    options.Cookie.HttpOnly = true;
    options.Cookie.IsEssential = true;
});
```

Add `app.UseSession()` after `app.UseRouting()`.

Modify your controller:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Index(UserSignInViewModel p)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        var result = await _signInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(p.username, p.password, false, true);
        if (result.Succeeded)
        {
            HttpContext.Session.SetString("kullanici", p.username); 
            return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
        }
        else
        {
            return RedirectToAction("Index", "Login");
        }
    }
    return View();
}
```

Update your header view to retrieve the username from the session:

```
<span>@HttpContext.Session.GetString("kullanici")</span>
```