# Why check for null reference in session variables results in ArgumentOutOfRangeException?

Tags: asp.net, iis

First line generating an exception when run at remote server. 
No error when running the code via IIS Express at my development notebook.

```
if (Session["LdapData"] == null) {
  // do something 
}
```

Exception:

> [ArgumentOutOfRangeException: Der Index lag außerhalb des Bereichs. Er
>   darf nicht negativ und kleiner als die Sammlung sein. Parametername:
>   index]    System.Collections.ArrayList.get_Item(Int32 index) +14539412
>   System.DirectoryServices.ResultPropertyValueCollection.get_Item(Int32
>   index) +93

Microsoft does it exactly the same way:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/03sekbw5(v=vs.100).aspx

```
if (Session["City"] == null) 
    // No such value in session state; take appropriate action.
```

Any ideas for debugging?

Edit:
Also read this articles, but didn´t get the point:

[Difference between Session and HttpContext.Current.Session](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/940742/difference-between-session-and-httpcontext-current-session)

[How to use sessions in an ASP.NET MVC 4 application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14138872/how-to-use-sessions-in-an-asp-net-mvc-4-application)

Comment: You showed too little code, so no one can easily guess what is `Session` in the snippet, except the fact that it is of `System.DirectoryServices.ResultPropertyValueCollection` type. I assume you ran an AD query and get such a result, then running on IIS Express and IIS are different because different credentials are used, https://blog.lextudio.com/web-application-differences-in-visual-studio-and-iis-60fec7e311b3 As a result, some queries can return different results, as IIS pool identity might not have the permissions on all properties.

Comment: if (System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session["LdapData"] == null) {}         "LdapData" is just a variable name I created.

Answer (score 0):

The exception was not related to the quoted line.
Don´t know why, but the displayed line number generated by the IIS is incorrect. Indeed the exception was caused by an ldap query some lines below in the code.